# Angular 14 how to show and hide child components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-components

I want to hide and show a Log in/Registration form on the bootstrap offcanvas component whenever I click a button but I don't know how to approach this problem.

The point is, when I click the *Log in* button of the navbar to open the offcanvas, I want to show the log in form by default. When I click on the *Register* button at the bottom of the log in component I want to hide the log in form and show the register component, and do the same with the *Log in* button on the register component.

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="d-flex">

           <a href="" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Log in</a>
           <app-login></app-login>
           <app-register></app-register>

       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

**login.component.html**

```
<!-- Offcanvas -->
<div class="offcanvas">
   <div class="offcanvas-body">
       <!-- Form -->
       <div>
           <form>
               <!-- Form inputs and labels-->
               <div>
                   <p> Don't have an account? <a href="">Register</a></p>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
       <!-- Form end -->
   </div>
   <!-- Offcanvas end -->
```

**register.component.html**

```
<!-- Offcanvas -->
<div class="offcanvas">
   <div class="offcanvas-body">
       <!-- Form -->
       <div>
           <form>
               <!-- Form inputs and labels -->
               <div>
                   <p> Already have an account? <a href="">Log in</a></p>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
       <!-- Form end -->
   </div>
   <!-- Offcanvas end -->
```

Is there a way to show and hide the components whenever I click the bottom button of the forms?

Comment: Are you very new in Angular? This is quite basic stuff so maybe follow some tutorials first?

Comment: I've been watching tutorials and I think the @Output directive on the child components is the way to go but the thing that the variable value should be changed from the child and not the parent confuses me, so I don't know how to aproach it very well. I'm also quite new to programming

Comment: I’m sorry, my comment could have been nicer. Seeing you need to control multiple components from multiple components (if I hnderstand you correctly) - a service would probably be the cleanest choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER:**

Apologies, I misread your question.

You need to assign an `#id` to the `href` of your links and then use that `id` in the `<div class="offcanvas">` of each component.

Here is a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/off-canvas-demo) with hopefully what you're looking for.

Of course, this is a simplified version for demonstration purposes. You have to fix the css, etc. according to your needs.

Cheers!

Comment: As it is an offcanvas component, URLs are not the issue here. If I could have done the form components on different pages I could easily change the URLs and navigate to another page, but as the Log in/Register components are inside an offcanvas, which is a "popup" at the top of the page, URLs are not changed whenever I open it. Or maybe I'm not getting what you meant.

Comment: @AntonioS Yeah, my bad. I misread your question. Hopefully, my updated answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow that solved my problem, and I thought it would be much harder to code. Thank you very much man!